# Throw Exception when set OutlineCode1 value on Export Data to Microsoft Office Project

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-project

I developed a Windows Forms Application with C# and SQL Server, I wrote this code to set OutlineCode1 value :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
...            
     task.OutlineCode1 = value.ToString();
```

when i set task.OutlineCode1 value, throw exception and i get this Error :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> "An unexpected error occurred with the method."

i tested all Microsoft Office Project interop version.

Answer (score 0):

The `OutlineCode1-10` fields are limited to values on the lookup list. First populate the list, then you can set the values. 
You can do this from the user interface or at runtime:

```
CustomFieldValueListAdd pjCustomTaskOutlineCode1, value.ToString()
```

(add object qualifiers as necessary)